# Google Maps API key for empty referrer - hybrid application

Tags: google-maps, cordova, google-maps-api-3

I'm making hybrid application that using some Google Maps API functionality.

Google maps are included using proper API key:

This key has some defined referrers at console API. Everything works properly when I open site as normal site. With some domain.

But when application is packed as native application for iOS - document.location.host is empty. So, the key is not valid because it doesn't match any referrer. Even "*".

What should I do in this case, to use cards with key in hydrid app?

Comment: @DenisObydennykh how did you remove all referrers?

Comment: @Brian I've made phonegap app that wrapped js/html into native container. And this html was opened from "localhost" of mobile OS. That's why there were no referrers.

Comment: @DenisObydennykh Thanks!