# Free Google Maps API for hybrid applications

Tags: google-maps

The Google Maps API has ["Unlimited free usage"](https://developers.google.com/maps/pricing-and-plans/#details) for Android and iOS, but only if their respective native SDK is involved. This allows developers to embed a Maps API key inside their (whitelisted) apps with no financial/operational consequences.

For Hybrid (Cordova) apps built to target Android/iOS, a key must be used to use the Maps API within the WebView:

```
<script src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.24&key=API_KEY_HERE&libraries=places"></script>
```

but the key has a quota indeed, for "Free up to 25,000 map loads per day". This allows someone to reverse engineer a hybrid app, abuse the given API key systematically, and cripple the operation of these hybrid apps. This also applies to API keys on the premium plan, whereby an attacker may waste developers' money through repeated API requests.

Since [the `referer` is empty inside a WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22745688/google-maps-api-key-for-empty-referrer-hybrid-application), I cannot whitelist a given referrer through the API key's Credentials section. I also cannot manipulate the `referer` of a script tag, even if it is dynamically injected in the document's `<head>`.

How can I create a free JS Maps API key that is whitelisted for my package (e.g. com.example.foo)?

Comment: I think this worth filing a feature request in the public issue tracker of Maps APIs: https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/

Comment: @xomena Do you think I should? It just seems too much of my own fault for expecting a Web API to know my package name, and my own fault for expecting Cordova to send a reasonable referer header, so maybe the community here has less demanding workarounds.

Comment: As far as I know Google uses value of window.location.href to check referers. In the case of Cordova application, it might be something like file://your/path. Currently you can set referer restriction for http://, probably it makes sense for file:// too. I see this as a valid feature request.

Comment: Are there news on this argument? It's 2018 and urls beginning for __file_url__ aren't working on hybrid apps